# How to forward email to another address with sendEmail(to,replyTo, subject, body)

Tags: google-apps-script

I appreciate if you could help.

I need to find all unread emails in my gmail 1@example.com and send them all to 2@example.com by using sendEmail(to,replyTo, subject, body) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

I tried to write a script but unfortinately it does not want work.
I hope you could help

```
function RespondEmail(e) {

//send response email
var threads = GmailApp.search("to:(1@example.com) label:unread");
for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
threads[i].sendEmail("1@example.com",
               "2@example.com",
               "TPS report status",
               "What is the status of those TPS reports?")}


// mark all as read
var threads = GmailApp.search("to:(1@example.com) label:unread");
GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
}
```

I also would be happy if you could advise me how I can change the subject of the ReplyTo email according  to original email which I receive on 1@example.com

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, it would be use to include what happens when you run the function. Do you get an error? What did you change or modify to make it work?

Answer (score 8):

The problem in your script lies in the fact that sendEmail() belongs to the GmailApp Service, so it always needs to be called the following way:

> GmailApp.sendEmail()

For your needs, it may be more appropriate to use the forward() method.

In the following example, I added a custom subject which you can edit and adapt to your needs.

```js
function RespondEmail() {

  //send response email
  var threads = GmailApp.search("to:origin@gmail.com is:unread");
  var subject = "";
  var msg = "";
  var c = 0; // will be used to count the messages in each thread
  var t = "";
  var attachment = "";
  var forwarded = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < 3 /*threads.length*/ ; i++) { 
    // I set 'i' to 3 so that you can test the function on your 3 most recent unread emails.
    // to use it on all your unread email, remove the 3 and remove the /* and */ signs.                   

    t = threads[i]; // I wanted to avoid repetition of "threads[i]" for the next 2 lines haha
    c = t.getMessageCount() - 1;
    msg = t.getMessages()[c];
    forwarded = msg.getBody(); // that is the body of the message we are forwarding.

    subject = msg.getSubject();
    attachment = msg.getAttachments();

    msg.forward("destination@gmail.com", {
      replyTo: "origin@gmail.com",
      subject: "TPS report status of [" + subject + "]", // customizes the subject
      htmlBody: "What is the status of those TPS reports below?<br><br>" //adds your message to the body
        +
        "<div style='text-align: center;'>---------- Forwarded message ----------</div><br>" + forwarded, //centers
      attachments: attachment
    });
    t.markRead(); // mark each forwarded thread as read, one by one

  }
}
```