# Forward all incoming gmail with appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, automation, gmail

As a newbie to Apps Script, I am trying to figure out how to forward all incoming email to multipul email adresses, using AppsScript. I have searched for scripts online, but they all seem to have more variables and conditions than I need. I am hoping for a simple solution.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message

Comment: You don't need apps script.  You can do it directly in settings. If you can't figure it out, ask at [webapps.se]

Comment: `I am hoping for a simple solution.` Consider the possibility that a script that, in your eyes, has `more variables and conditions than I need` is actually a simple solution that merely has more options than you need. For example [Forward incoming mail with appscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75489634/1330560). BTW, what are the variables and conditions that you need? As it stands, your question is rhetorical; you haven't described any specific requirements.

Comment: @Tedinoz i tried to use the code but it doesnt work, it uses the same last email again and again, if Frank ARV would post a new one would be the best

Comment: `i tried to use the code but it doesnt work, it uses the same last email again and again` would you please edit your question and include _your_ script, and also explain in more detail what you mean by `it uses the same last email again and again`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to forward email to another address with sendEmail(to,replyTo, subject, body)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790496/how-to-forward-email-to-another-address-with-sendemailto-replyto-subject-body)

Answer (score 0):

You want to forward all incoming Gmail to several people..

`fwdNewEmail`: run this function

- queries Gmail threads for new email
- forwards the email
- "marks" the email `as read`

---

**ISSUES TO NOTE**

**Triggering the function**

- There are no built-in triggers for Gmail. So the project is structured as follows:

  - create a new spreadsheet and use the Project Editor for the spreadsheet.
  - create a `time-driven trigger` for `fwdNewEmail`

    - the frequency will depend on your circumstances.

**Email addresses of Contacts**

- enter the email addresses as a comma separated string.

h/t: @AntoineColson - [How to forward email to another address with sendEmail(to,replyTo, subject, body)]
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793642/1330560)

---

```
/*
// forward all incoming e-mail 
// to: multiple people
// Values to update:
// - "fwdAddresses" - a comma separarted string
// - sendersEmail
// - Gmail search query
*/

function fwdNewEmail(){
  var fwdAddresses = "Insert forwarding email addresses" // such as "recipient1@example.com,recipient2@example.com"
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the forwarding addreses are:"+fwdAddresses)

  var sendersEmail = "Insert sender email address"

  // get threads
  var threads = GmailApp.search("is:unread newer_than:1d");
  // Logger.log(threads) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log(threads.length) // DEBUG
  
  // loop through threads
  for (var i=0;i<threads.length;i++){
    var thread = threads[i]
    var msgs = thread.getMessages()
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of messages="+msgs.length)

    // loop through thread messages
    for (var m=0;m<msgs.length;m++){
      var message = msgs[m]
      var messageBody = message.getBody()
      var messageFrom = message.getFrom()
      var messageUnRead = message.isUnread()
      var messageSubject = message.getSubject()
      var messageAttachment = message.getAttachments()
      if(messageFrom === sendersEmail)
      {
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Not Forwarded: Sender=me: Thread#:"+i+" message#:"+m+" from: "+message.getFrom())
        continue
      }
      if(messageUnRead === false){
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: Not forwarded: Message is Read: Thread#:"+i+" message#:"+m+" from: "+message.getFrom()+" read status: "+messageUnRead)
        continue
      }

      // Logger.log("DEBUG: To be forwarded: Thread#:"+i+" message#:"+m+" from: "+message.getFrom()+" read status: "+messageUnRead+" subject: "+messageSubject)

      var forwarded = message.getBody(); // that is the body of the message we are forwarding.   

      message.forward(fwdAddresses, {
        replyTo: "Insert Replyto email address",
        subject: "Forwarded: [" + messageSubject + "]", // customizes the subject
        htmlBody: "This is a message that I received<br><br>" //adds your message to the body
          +
          "<div style='text-align: center;'>---------- Forwarded message ----------</div><br>" + messageBody, //centers
        attachments: messageAttachment
      });

      message.markRead(); // mark each forwarded thread as read, one by one
    }
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Execution log
11:56:58 AM Notice Execution started
11:56:58 AM Notice Execution completed

Comment: I dont see anyfwd action done, can you clarify why?

Comment: `can you clarify why` No but but I am guessing that it is just a matter of "configuration" &/or whether the search query is finding any unread emails. Anyway: the script includes several `Logger` statements - "un-comment" all of them and then run  `fwdNewEmail`. You should see the number of threads and the proposed treatment for each message within each thread. In the meantime, I'll try and get us in chat. Where in the world are you? (I'm in Sydney, Australia).

Comment: #2:`can you clarify why`. Have you checked the "Executions" log to see whether the script "completed" or "failed"? If it failed, then what was the reason?